# Form screenshot at specific form size

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to make a C# Form screenshot, but there is a catch.

I need it to be a form at certain resolution AND form itself must not flicker to a user, so somehow in background it need to make an screenshot at certain form dimension.

I tried various things but i cannot make form resized without actually resize a window and than take a screenshot. It's anoying since, to user a window will flicker in mean time -> go to resolution -> make screen shot -> go back to old resolution.

Making a deep-copy of form is a more or less no go since it would needed a lot of rewriting things.

I tried things like: [Attempt 1](https://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/) | [Attempt 2](http://www.xtremedotnettalk.com/graphics-and-multimedia/95011-capture-hidden-window-top-level.html) | [Attempt 3](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/260393/get-bitmap-of-hidden-window)

But still problem with resizing window and flicker from one size to other.

I have dotnet 2.0 (don't ask why).

Comment: You could try to a) take a snapshot of the form as it is, overlay another form with this image as background then do the rest, ie resizing and snapshoting the form. Finally resize again and close the overlay.. - But of course the simplest approach is to tell the user it will and must flicker a bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used solution was to paint seperate picture boxes to the memory and than merge all this seperate images to one big image.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific problem, and I'm sure there are no real code solutions for that. This is a design-technical issue, and some possible ways to avoid this are
1. You don't resize the form back,
2. You make screenshots only possible in your specific size,
3. You disable the resizing in general and set your size to the default size.